# Wp-admin page is showing blank. How to get back my wp-admin page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theming

Wp-admin or wp-login.php is blank.  First time I'm having this problem. 
I use godaddy basic wp plan.   I can't reinstall wordpress 
But I have tried by changing the "wp-Sg7k4r-options"  folder name.
I renamed  the theme and trying to deactivate plugins. But still I have the problem. The "information -scheme" shows some plugins still active.
I don't understand what to do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have access to the database you can set the theme back to the default theme ..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

**Turn on `WP Debug`.**

There is a good chance that you are seeing the error because of any PHP errors. And once you turn on `WP_DEBUG`, it will show you all the errors which you can track and fix the error.

How to debug:

Open wp-config.php file in your editor and add the following code to it.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```